# Regular Expression to detect image tag

Tags: regex

I'm trying use regular expression

```
<img __defa([^>]*)(.+?)my_macro_movingImage24Pro([^>]*)/>
```

for below string.
I need to detect 3 image strings containing "my_macro_movingImage24Pro"
Ideally I need to retrieve 3 matches. But first 2 matches are overlapping as 1.
Can anybody help?

```
<body><p><strong>asifalsfhlshlsdasd</strong></p><p></p><p>Business
aso;i;dfhd;sdafhsa;fhds;lfsaffas.</p><p></p><p><strong>Video
 I: safhsdlkfsddd</strong></p><p>asfsadfsafafsaadff.</p><p></p><p><img __default_attr="sfdsdfss" my_macro_name="sdfsdsd" class="my_macro my_macro_movingImage24Pro" data-renderedposition="239_8
427_252" height="250" src="/dfsfds/sdfsd1619a91/images/sdfd/plugins/dfd/images/spacer.gif" width="425"/></p><p></p><p><strong>Video II: </strong><strong>sdfsadfsafs</strong><strong> (~ 3 min.)<br/></strong></p><p>dsfsdfsff.</p><p></p><p><img __default_attr="sfdsdfss" my_macro_name="sdfsdsd" class="my_macro my_macro_movingImage24Pro" data-renderedposition="575_8_427_252" height="250" src="/dfsfds/sdfsd1619a91/images/sdfd/plugins/dfd/images/spacer.gif" width="425"/></p><p></p><p><strong>Video III: </strong><strong>sdfasdfsadf</
strong><strong> (~ 3 min.)</strong></p><p>Are you a people manager? asfsdafsaf.</p><p></p><p><img __default_attr="sfdsdfss" my_macro_name="sdfsdsd" class="my_macro my_macro_movingImage24Pro" data-renderedposition="911_8_427_252" height="250" src="/dfsfds/sdfsd1619a91/images/sdfd/plugins/dfd/images/spacer.gif" width="425"/></p><p></p><p>These videos are also posted on the <a _dser_internal="true" href="/sdf/asfdgcs/sfd/operations/sdfs-management"><strong>asfdsd Intranet page</strong> </a>dgfafdgadgg.</p><p></p><p>sfasfasdfasfaf <a href="XXXX" target="_blank"><strong>XXX</strong></a> (non-emergency on
ly).</p></body>
```

Comment: Most frameworks have an html parser that saves writing this sort of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is nearly correct. The problematic part is `(.+?)`. That part of regex can match anything. Following regex is working for me on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ThGoeA/3)

```
<img [^>]*my_macro_movingImage24Pro[^>]*\/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `img` tag is in two lines, either you preprocess the text to avoid this or you use the `s` modifier to treat input as a single line.

```
(?s)<img.*?my_macro_movingImage24Pro.*?\/>
```

[live example in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZiNAY0/2)